# AngularJS - How to share watched objects in several controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My current controllers are filled with logic that hides button on submit, and shows success message after backend fetched data:

```
angular.module('testApp').controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'testService',
    function ($scope, testService) {

    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.updated = false;
    $scope.error = false;

    $scope.submit = function() {
      if(!$scope.form.$valid) {
        return;
      }

      $scope.loading = true;
      testService.doBackendUpdate({some:'data'})
        .success(function() {
          $scope.error = $scope.loading = false;
          $scope.updated = true;
        })
        .error(function(error) {
          $scope.updated = $scope.loading = false;
          $scope.error = true;
        });
    };
  }]);
```

And html:

```
 <alert type="'success'" close="updated = false" ng-show="updated">Data Updated!</alert>

 <button ng-hide="loading">update</button>
```

What i would like to have instead of those variables is some kind of object, and reuse it
on other controllers:

```
angular.module('testApp').controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'testService',
    function ($scope, testService) {

    $scope.status = new ActionStatus();

    $scope.submit = function() {
      if(!$scope.form.$valid) {
        return;
      }

      $scope.status.loading();
      testService.doBackendUpdate({some:'data'})
        .success(function() {
          $scope.status.succes();
        })
        .error(function(error) {
          $scope.status.error();
        });
    };
  }]);
```

And html:

```
 <alert type="'success'" close="updated = false" ng-show="status.isUpdated">Data Updated!</alert>

 <button ng-hide="statuss.isLoading">update</button>
```

But how could i accomplish this? AngularJS watch loses context when watching variable, so i cannot simply create an ActionStatus object via prototyping.

Any ideas?

Comment: Extract it to a [**service**](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)? e.g. `.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'testService', 'ActionStatus', function ($scope, testService, ActionStatus) { $scope.status = ActionStatus; ...`

Comment: But services are singletons. and if i have two controllers on the same page...?

Answer (score 3):

To share objects between several controllers you should create a service.

Example:

```
// Custom object
function ActionStatus() {
  this.isLoading = false;
  this.updated = false;
  this.error = false;
  this.loading = function() {};

}

angular.module('testApp').service('actionStatus', [ActionStatus]);

// Inject object factory dependency to your controller.
angular.module('testApp').controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'testService', 'actionStatus',
function ($scope, testService, actionStatus ) {

 $scope.status = actionStatus;

 }]);
```

The problem here is that services are singletons and are instantiated with `new` keyword.

To share the object prototype and handle the instantiation yourself, the factory method can be used. The factory should return the constructor of your prototype like this:

```
app.factory('actionStatus', [function() {

 // Define constructor
 function ActionStatus() {
   this.isLoading = false;
   this.updated = false;
   this.error = false;
   this.loading = function() {};
   this.stopLoading = function() {
    this.isLoading = false;
   };
 }

 // Return constructor to handle the instantiation yourself.
 return ActionStatus; 
}]);
```

I created a working example on plnkr for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wd4kmg?p=preview

More information on that:

http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/guide/providers

Comment: And what if i have to controllers on the same page? Services are singletons.

Comment: it's a singleton alright, which is exactly what you want. Both controllers will have access to the same singleton, which allows you to share data.

Comment: I don't want to share them, i want to reuse them as new objects, that is why i stated that cannot use prototypes

Comment: Here i prepared a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wd4kmg?p=preview using a factory that returns the constructor to let your self the handle of instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

There three ways I can think about:

1. Put it into `$rootScope`.
2. Put it into a service/factory, and use a messaging system (`$broadcast`, `$emit`, `$on`) to communicate each other.
3. Similar to the 2nd option, just watch the service by `objectEquality` set to true, like so:

   ```js
   $watch(WhateverService.get(), functiondoTheJob(){...}, true)
   ```